# Retrieve TcpClient from Hashlist

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am developing a chat program in C# that an open telnet port for administration. The deal is that every time a client connects to the server, the server stores his nickname and socket in a hashlist. Is there a way to retrieve the TcpClient back so that I can do `TcpClient.Disconnect()` or `Close()` ?

My Code:

```
// When the client enters the server
   clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);
// This will add the nick and tcpclient to the Hashtable
```

Is there a way to retrieve it back so that I can do `Close()` or `disconnect()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give tou TcpClient:

```
 clientsList[dataFromClient]
```

Comment: TcpClient userToKick = (TcpClient)Program.clientsList[Convert.ToInt32(output)];